# Java VM EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION WITH JNI?

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, dll, java-native-interface

If anyone can help me with my problem.
    when I try to run a function from the DLL by using the API java jni the JMV generates this exeception:

```
#
# An unexpected error has been detected by Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000077503290, pid=4796, tid=5348
#
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (10.0-b19 mixed mode windows-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ntdll.dll+0x53290]
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\MSKANE\Desktop\WorkSpace\SP\hs_err_pid4796.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
```

find below the log file:

```
#
# An unexpected error has been detected by Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000077503290, pid=5868, tid=5200
#
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (10.0-b19 mixed mode windows-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ntdll.dll+0x53290]
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

```
Current thread (0x0000000005b1bc00):  JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_in_vm, id=5200, stack(0x0000000006e50000,0x0000000006f50000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x00000bf7a90de2a8

Registers:
EAX=0x000000fd00000041, EBX=0x00000bf7a90de2a0, ECX=0x000000ffffffffff, EDX=0x00000000003d5630
ESP=0x0000000006f4e550, EBP=0x0000000000000000, ESI=0x0000000000340000, EDI=0x00000000003d5640
EIP=0x0000000077503290, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010206

Top of Stack: (sp=0x0000000006f4e550)
0x0000000006f4e550:   00000000003d5640 0000000000000000
0x0000000006f4e560:   fffffffffffffffe 0000000000000000
0x0000000006f4e570:   0000000000000000 000007fefa686f73
0x0000000006f4e580:   0000000006f4e5e0 0000000000000000
0x0000000006f4e590:   0000000005b1bc00 0000000006f4ebe8
0x0000000006f4e5a0:   00000000103d8d00 0000000000000102
0x0000000006f4e5b0:   0000000000000000 00000000003d5640
0x0000000006f4e5c0:   0000000006f4eba0 000007fefed610c8
0x0000000006f4e5d0:   0000000000000000 0000000005b1bc00
0x0000000006f4e5e0:   000007fefa6a73b0 0000000000000003
0x0000000006f4e5f0:   0000000005b1bc00 00000000081c1b4f
0x0000000006f4e600:   0000000000000000 000007fefa6a73a8
0x0000000006f4e610:   0000000006f4e650 0000000010538588
0x0000000006f4e620:   00000000103d8d00 0000000180002be4
0x0000000006f4e630:   00000000103d8d00 0000000006f4eba0
0x0000000006f4e640:   0000000010538588 0000000006f4e650 

Instructions: (pc=0x0000000077503290)
0x0000000077503280:   33 d8 48 33 1d 3f f1 0d 00 48 c1 e3 04 0f 0d 0b
0x0000000077503290:   4c 8b 63 08 49 bd 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 49 be 


Stack: [0x0000000006e50000,0x0000000006f50000],  sp=0x0000000006f4e550,  free space=1017k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [ntdll.dll+0x53290]

[error occurred during error reporting (printing native stack), id 0xc0000005]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::Interpreter
v  ~BufferBlob::StubRoutines (1)

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x0000000007062400 JavaThread "TimerQueue" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1648, stack(0x0000000007350000,0x0000000007450000)]
  0x000000000034a800 JavaThread "DestroyJavaVM" [_thread_blocked, id=2504, stack(0x0000000002090000,0x0000000002190000)]
=>0x0000000005b1bc00 JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_in_vm, id=5200, stack(0x0000000006e50000,0x0000000006f50000)]
  0x0000000005b1b400 JavaThread "AWT-Windows" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=1120, stack(0x0000000006d50000,0x0000000006e50000)]
  0x0000000005b19000 JavaThread "AWT-Shutdown" [_thread_blocked, id=5752, stack(0x0000000006c50000,0x0000000006d50000)]
  0x0000000005b18000 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3412, stack(0x0000000006b50000,0x0000000006c50000)]
  0x0000000005ab1400 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4580, stack(0x00000000062e0000,0x00000000063e0000)]
  0x0000000005aadc00 JavaThread "CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6140, stack(0x00000000061e0000,0x00000000062e0000)]
  0x0000000005aa4000 JavaThread "CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4428, stack(0x00000000060e0000,0x00000000061e0000)]
  0x0000000005aa2000 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4620, stack(0x0000000005fe0000,0x00000000060e0000)]
  0x0000000005aa1800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5100, stack(0x0000000005ee0000,0x0000000005fe0000)]
  0x0000000005a85c00 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2264, stack(0x0000000005de0000,0x0000000005ee0000)]
  0x0000000005a84c00 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=496, stack(0x0000000005ce0000,0x0000000005de0000)]

Other Threads:
  0x0000000005a80c00 VMThread [stack: 0x0000000005be0000,0x0000000005ce0000] [id=3528]
  0x0000000005ab2000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x00000000063e0000,0x00000000064e0000] [id=1768]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 19008K, used 4559K [0x000000003fac0000, 0x0000000040ff0000, 0x0000000054e10000)
  eden space 16320K, 27% used [0x000000003fac0000,0x000000003ff33e78,0x0000000040ab0000)
  from space 2688K, 0% used [0x0000000040d50000,0x0000000040d50000,0x0000000040ff0000)
  to   space 2688K, 0% used [0x0000000040ab0000,0x0000000040ab0000,0x0000000040d50000)
 PSOldGen        total 43392K, used 0K [0x0000000015410000, 0x0000000017e70000, 0x000000003fac0000)
  object space 43392K, 0% used [0x0000000015410000,0x0000000015410000,0x0000000017e70000)
 PSPermGen       total 21248K, used 11569K [0x0000000010010000, 0x00000000114d0000, 0x0000000015410000)
  object space 21248K, 54% used [0x0000000010010000,0x0000000010b5c460,0x00000000114d0000)

Dynamic libraries:
0x0000000000400000 - 0x000000000042e000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_04\bin\javaw.exe
0x00000000774b0000 - 0x0000000077659000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x0000000077290000 - 0x00000000773af000     C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
0x000007fefd4c0000 - 0x000007fefd52c000     C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x000007fefea30000 - 0x000007fefeb0b000     C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x000007fefed60000 - 0x000007fefedff000     C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x000007fefea10000 - 0x000007fefea2f000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
0x000007feff270000 - 0x000007feff39d000     C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x00000000773b0000 - 0x00000000774aa000     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
0x000007feff640000 - 0x000007feff6a7000     C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
0x000007fefee00000 - 0x000007fefee0e000     C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll
0x000007fefd9b0000 - 0x000007fefda79000     C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll
0x000007feff480000 - 0x000007feff4ae000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x000007feff6b0000 - 0x000007feff7b9000     C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x0000000008000000 - 0x00000000085aa000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_04\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x000007fefa520000 - 0x000007fefa55b000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x0000000010000000 - 0x000000001000a000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_04\jre\bin\hpi.dll
0x0000000077670000 - 0x0000000077677000     C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x0000000000320000 - 0x000000000032e000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_04\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x0000000000350000 - 0x0000000000377000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_04\jre\bin\java.dll
0x0000000000380000 - 0x0000000000392000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_04\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x00000000064e0000 - 0x000000000667f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_04\jre\bin\awt.dll
0x000007fef5c00000 - 0x000007fef5c71000     C:\Windows\system32\WINSPOOL.DRV
0x000007fefee10000 - 0x000007feff013000     C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
0x000007fefdaa0000 - 0x000007fefe828000     C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
0x000007fefeb10000 - 0x000007fefeb81000     C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x0000000180000000 - 0x0000000180071000     C:\Windows\System32\Jacspcsc.dll
0x000007fefbd80000 - 0x000007fefbdd6000     C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x000007fefb820000 - 0x000007fefb838000     C:\Windows\system32\dwmapi.dll
0x000007fefd110000 - 0x000007fefd11f000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x0000000006760000 - 0x00000000067ca000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_04\jre\bin\fontmanager.dll
0x0000000001d50000 - 0x0000000001d67000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_04\jre\bin\net.dll
0x000007fefeb90000 - 0x000007fefebdd000     C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x000007fefd900000 - 0x000007fefd908000     C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
0x000007fefca50000 - 0x000007fefcaa5000     C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
0x000007fefca40000 - 0x000007fefca47000     C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll
0x0000000001d80000 - 0x0000000001d8b000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_04\jre\bin\nio.dll
0x000007feff3a0000 - 0x000007feff477000     C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.DLL
0x000007fefa680000 - 0x000007fefa6b8000     C:\Windows\system32\winscard.dll
0x000007fefc6b0000 - 0x000007fefc6ed000     C:\Windows\system32\WINSTA.dll
0x000007fefc400000 - 0x000007fefc411000     C:\Windows\system32\WTSAPI32.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 
java_command: ACOS3ConfigureATR
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_04
PATH=path:C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\developpement\tools\apache-maven-3.2.3/bin;C:\developpement\tools\apache-ant-1.9.3/bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_04/bin
USERNAME=mskane
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows NT 6.1 Build 7601 Service Pack 1

CPU:total 4 (8 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 10 stepping 9, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, ht

Memory: 4k page, physical 4163652k(1915224k free), swap 8325440k(4680436k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (10.0-b19) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.6.0_04-b12), built on Dec 14 2007 00:44:23 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 8.0

time: Fri Dec 26 16:32:29 2014
elapsed time: 1 seconds
```